# Circular stacked barplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run this code from this link https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html.

```
# library
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
 
# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=c( rep('A', 10), rep('B', 30), rep('C', 14), rep('D', 6)) ,
  value1=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T),
  value2=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T),
  value3=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)
 
# Transform data in a tidy format (long format)
data <- data %>% gather(key = "observation", value="value", -c(1,2)) 
 
# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 2
nObsType <- nlevels(as.factor(data$observation))
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group)*nObsType, ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar*nObsType )
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group, individual)
data$id <- rep( seq(1, nrow(data)/nObsType) , each=nObsType)
 
# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data %>% group_by(id, individual) %>% summarize(tot=sum(value))
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)
 
# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))
 
# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]
 
# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data) +      
  
  # Add the stacked bar
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=observation), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +
  
  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 0, xend = start, yend = 0), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 50, xend = start, yend = 50), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 100, xend = start, yend = 100), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 150, xend = start, yend = 150), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 200, xend = start, yend = 200), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),5), y = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), label = c("0", "50", "100", "150", "200") , color="grey", size=6 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
  
  ylim(-150,max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  
  # Add labels on top of each bar
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=tot+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)


# Save at png
ggsave(p, file="output.png", width=10, height=10)
```

However, I am not sure why I am not getting the gaps and the scales in my figure (see below). As depicted, the numbers are printed inside the figure and the gaps between different groups of data are not there.
[image]

The original figure should be as follows:

[image: The original figure should be as follows:]

Comment: while not an answer to the particular issue, package `circlize` is all about circular plots; might be helpful for other occasions: https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize/

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the code. `group` has to be a `factor` to make the code adding the gaps work. To fix this add `data$group <- factor(data$group)`.

Note: My guess is that the reason for this bug is that as of version 4.0.0 R treats strings in data frames as strings rather than factors. Hence, for versions < 4.0.0 the code worked fine as is.

```r
# library
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual = paste("Mister ", seq(1, 60), sep = ""),
  group = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 30), rep("C", 14), rep("D", 6)),
  value1 = sample(seq(10, 100), 60, replace = T),
  value2 = sample(seq(10, 100), 60, replace = T),
  value3 = sample(seq(10, 100), 60, replace = T)
)
# Convert to factor
data$group <- factor(data$group)

# Transform data in a tidy format (long format)
data <- data %>% gather(key = "observation", value = "value", -c(1, 2))

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 2
nObsType <- nlevels(as.factor(data$observation))
to_add <- data.frame(matrix(NA, empty_bar * nlevels(data$group) * nObsType, ncol(data)))
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each = empty_bar * nObsType)
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group, individual)
data$id <- rep(seq(1, nrow(data) / nObsType), each = nObsType)

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data %>%
  group_by(id, individual) %>%
  summarize(tot = sum(value))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id - 0.5) / number_of_bar # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse(angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle + 180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(start = min(id), end = max(id) - empty_bar) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(title = mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[c(nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data) - 1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1, ]

# Make the plot
ggplot(data) +

  # Add the stacked bar
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(id), y = value, fill = observation), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +

  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data = grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 0, xend = start, yend = 0), colour = "grey", alpha = 1, size = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(data = grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 50, xend = start, yend = 50), colour = "grey", alpha = 1, size = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(data = grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 100, xend = start, yend = 100), colour = "grey", alpha = 1, size = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(data = grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 150, xend = start, yend = 150), colour = "grey", alpha = 1, size = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(data = grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 200, xend = start, yend = 200), colour = "grey", alpha = 1, size = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +

  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id), 5), y = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), label = c("0", "50", "100", "150", "200"), color = "grey", size = 6, angle = 0, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1) +
  ylim(-150, max(label_data$tot, na.rm = T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1, 4), "cm")
  ) +
  coord_polar() +

  # Add labels on top of each bar
  geom_text(data = label_data, aes(x = id, y = tot + 10, label = individual, hjust = hjust), color = "black", fontface = "bold", alpha = 0.6, size = 5, angle = label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE) +

  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data = base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, size = 0.6, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label = group), hjust = c(1, 1, 0, 0), colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, size = 4, fontface = "bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)
#> Warning: Removed 24 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
#> Warning: Removed 9 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]

Comment: lol, just saw this in the active questions, and I am glad we found the same solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616495/circular-barchart-customization-from-r-graph-gallery

Comment: @tjebo Yep. Same issue, same answer. :D Thx for closing as a duplicate.